# How do you update a portion of an html page when submitting a form on selecting a checkbox?

Tags: php, html, forms, post, checkbox

I have the following code:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['myCheckBox']))
    {
        //Checkbox1 is selected
        echo "helloword 1: [".$office."]";
        $checked = "checked";
     }
     else
    {
       //alternate code
       echo "helloword 2: [".$office."]";
       $checked = "";
    }
?>

<form name="checkbox" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
    <input type="checkbox" name="myCheckBox" value="<?php echo $office;?>" onClick='submit();' <?php echo $checked;?>>
</form>
```

How do you update a portion of the html page when submitting a form so the whole page doesn't reload? Also is this the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think ajax will suit you, especially the [jquery.form](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) plugin, you can submit the form use this plugin without refreshing the page.

Comment: there are many examples in the website, you can see it here http://jquery.malsup.com/form/ , hope helps